# How to make a relationship with Spree::User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solidus

I am trying to build a friends feature on top of the Solidus framework but am having trouble establishing a many-many relationship with Spree::Users. I tried making a user_decorator.rb file (in models/spree) but keep encountering the error: "expected user_decorator.rb to define Spree::UserDecorator, but didn't".

User Decorator:

```
 Spree::User.class_eval do
   has_many :friendships
   has_many :friends, through: :friendships
 end
```

Friendship Model:

```
 class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :spree_user, :class_name => 'Spree::User'
   belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'Spree::User'
 end
```

Error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOpEU.png

Comment: Rails is easy but if you know `how_to` :) The file user_decorator.rb expects UserDecorator defined in it. If you have it defined already then it should be include in it. As far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Replace content in `app/models/spree/user_decorator` with:

```
module Spree
  module UserDecorator
    def self.prepended(base)
      base.has_many :friendships
      base.has_many :friends, through: :friendships
    end

    Spree::User.prepend self
  end
end
```